# How to compare two different dates in velocity in Java?

Tags: velocity

```
 #set( $currentDate = 'June 1,2016')

 #set( $SettleDate = 'Dec 1,2016')

    #if( $currentDate < $SettleDate)

      <li>xyz</li>

    #end
```

Comment: is this java  or am I missing something in my life ?

Comment: You canot perform `lessthan` of `greater than` in date its good to use `after` and` before` operation

Answer (score 1):

You can use [comparison tool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ComparisonDateTool.html) with `difference` function

```
  $date.difference('2016-12-01','2016-06-01')
```

Or  `whenIs`

```
  $date.whenIs('2016-12-01','2016-06-01')
```

Comment: actually my intention is want to compare the before the six months date . if it is true in the sense i need to print some line . what is the exact solution for this problem